# SQL Update Query with two levels of join?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm trying to put together an update query where the source field is two tables away.  Here's a query I got to work in the SQLCMD window which pulls both fields when they don't match:

```
SELECT 
    Act_det.Shift AS Shift_a, Inc_main.Shift AS Shift_b,
FROM 
    dbo.Act_det
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Act_main ON Act_det.Activ_id = Act_main.Activ_id
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Inc_main ON Act_main.Inci_no = Inc_main.Inci_no
WHERE
    Act_det.Shift <> Inc_main.Shift;
```

I want to set `Act_det.Shift = Inc.main_Shift` when they don't match.

The relationships are that the Act_det table has a field `Activ_id` which matches to a single record in the `Act_main` table.  The `Act_main` then has an `inci_no` which matches to a single record in the `Inc_main` table which has the "shift" value that we want to query and update "shift" in the act-det table with if they don't already match.

I've tried putting together an update query based on other responses found here and other places but I can't figure out how to make an Update/Set and the joins coexist.

```
UPDATE dbo.Act_det
SET db.act_det.shift = dbo.inc_main.shift,
INNER JOIN dbo.Act_main ON Act_det.Activ_id = Act_main.Activ_id
INNER JOIN dbo.Inc_main ON Act_main.Inci_no = Inc_main.Inci_no
WHERE Act_det.Shift <> Inc_main.Shift;
```

This bombs out with

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

I can't just update every record even if they already match, since at the application level every Incident that gets updated will get flagged for re-submission to the state, and we'll end up with like 15,000 records going up for audit.

Comment: You have extra commas at line ends, read the grammar. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debug fundamental.) Debug questions require a [mre]. That includes DBMS/SQL. [ask] [Help] Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please format code reasonably. Please avoid social/meta content. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: I should've added that- I did also attempt with no commas, since none are needed- they were an artifact from my original "Select" with multiple elements and I realized that after my initial failure.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete/flag obsolete comments.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.

Comment: I presume you're using SQL Server - in which case you're missing a 'FROM' (and have an extra comma). Also you have a 'db' where it should be either 'dbo' or blank in the 'set' area. It should start as `Update dbo.Act_det set shift = dbo.inc_main.shift FROM dbo.Act_det INNER JOIN dbo.Act_main` etc

Answer (score 0):

I did post the improper "latest" version of my attempts. (When cutting and pasting from OneNote it wants to do it as a picture, so I ended up using the up arrow in the SQLCMD and landed on a prior attempt.) I had it formatted with a FROM and without the extraneous comma. BUT I never caught me having `dbo` instead of `db`.

From the comments:

> I presume you're using SQL Server - in which case you're missing a 'FROM' (and have an extra comma). Also you have a 'db' where it should be either 'dbo' or blank in the 'set' area. It should start as Update dbo.Act_det set shift = dbo.inc_main.shift FROM dbo.Act_det INNER JOIN dbo.Act_main etc –
> [seanb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14267425/seanb)